# No HDMI signal with i3 + Denon amp

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, hdmi, signal, amplification

My setup used to worked perfectly :

Windows 10 + i3 4330 --HDMI--> Denon amplifier --HDMI--> Samsung TV

One day, I got a power outage. But once it went back, my HTPC stopped sending signal to my Denon.

When I plug directly the HDMI to the TV, it works.
When I plug it to the amp, the amp says No Signal. I have tried another input and different cable.

All drivers are up to date, Bios,chipset,graphic card (HD 4600).

When I disable the graphic card in the Peripheral manager, I get signal out of the amp. As soon as I enable it, it stops working.

When I reboot, I don't see the Bios messages either. Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like the computer is fine since it works directly with the TV.  That leaves the amp.  Have you tried using another HDMI input (like cable or another computer) on the amp to see if the amp was damaged?

Comment: I'm puzzled by what you say. When you disable the graphics card what does `System`->`Display` show? And what signal do you get from the disabled card?

Comment: @Keltari, I have tried on my TV receiver input which works, with 2 different cable, no luck.

Comment: @AFH, when the graphic card is disabled, I can see my desktop through the amp. Not sure about what Display show, will check tonight.

Comment: Look also at `Advanced display settings`, and check `Control Panel` settings, such as the display and monitor settings in `Device Manager` and `Intel® HD Graphics` if you have it.

Comment: I updated Windows 10 and somehow I got the signal back to the amp. But DTS sound were not working, I kept playing with it, and now hdmi is not working directly on TV...

Comment: Now, I have a computer monitor on a DVI-to-HDMI. If I also plug the HDMI to the amp, bath screen are black. I have to unplug HDMI so that I can see on the computer monitor.

Comment: It ended up being the Samsung H8000 TV, the HDMI 3 ARC port is somehow broken (maybe due to an update, this would explain the sudden error). On HDMI 4, the only one that works, the image was actually bigger than the screen, other than that everything worked.